# How can I detect whether the timeout in Python's subprocess has been reached?

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to differentiate between failed processes and timed-out processes. Python *does* catch the error and clearly identifies it. That is good, but no cigar, because I'd like to write my own log message that corresponds to the timeout error. See below for my current implementation and an explanation of what I want.

If program something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
My job is to demonstrate a problem detecting timeout failures. 
"""

import os
import sys
import logging
import subprocess
import time

# Create main (root) logging object
logger = logging.getLogger('{}'.format(__file__))
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Formatter
consoleh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
consoleh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
console_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s   %(name)s   PID: %(process)d   TID: %(thread)d   %(levelname)s \n ==> %(message)s',datefmt='%Y-%m-%d at %H:%M:%S.%s')
consoleh.setFormatter(console_formatter)
logger.addHandler(consoleh)

def preHook(script):
  logger.debug('preHook called.')
  command = "{}".format(script)
  logger.info('preHook Executing with 15 second timeout: \n     /bin/sh -c {}'.format(command))
  process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)# timeout in seconds
  process.wait(timeout=15)
  proc_stdout, proc_stderr = process.communicate()
  if process.returncode == 0:
    logger.info('preHook: Process complete: \n     Command: /bin/sh -c {}\n     STDOUT: "{}"\n     STDERR: "{}"\n     Exit Code: {}\n     at: {}'.format(command,proc_stdout.decode('utf8').strip(),proc_stderr.decode('utf8').strip(),process.returncode,time.time()))
  else:
    exitcode = 1
    logger.error('preHook: Process failed: \n     Command: /bin/sh -c {}\n     STDOUT: "{}"\n     STDERR: "{}"\n     Exit Code: {}\n     at: {}'.format(command,proc_stdout.decode('utf8').strip(), proc_stderr.decode('utf8').strip(),process.returncode,time.time()))

def main():
  preHook('find -type f')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

How can I catch the timeout error and write a related message in the standard error output?

## Console Output

Python' subprocess package clearly catches the timeout error.

```
2017-08-28 at 09:44:57.1503906297   detecttimeout.py   PID: 16915   TID: 140534594959104   INFO
 ==> preHook Executing with 15 second timeout:
     /bin/sh -c find -type f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detecttimeout.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "detecttimeout.py", line 37, in main
    preHook('find -type f')
  File "detecttimeout.py", line 28, in preHook
    process.wait(timeout=15)
  File "/home/USER/devel/python/Python-3.4.5/Lib/subprocess.py", line 1561, in wait
    raise TimeoutExpired(self.args, timeout)
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command 'find -type f' timed out after 15 seconds
```

I'd like to catch the timeout like I do the failed process. To implement catching failed processes, I use the return codes as shown in the logic. The message `preHook: Process failed...` occurs. I'd like another message: `preHook: Process timed out...`.

Comment: Why not simply catching the `TimeoutExpired` exception and write the message you want in the except clause?

Comment: @Anis Sure, could you help me by providing an answer that describes how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace

```
process.wait(timeout=15)
```

by

```
try:
    process.wait(timeout=15)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    logger.error(<your error message>)
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

Just catch the error

```
try:
  process.wait(timeout=15)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
  logger.error(e) #logs the default error from subprocess.TimeoutExpired
  logger.error("Boom")
  return
```

Edit: Made more accurate and logs the error message as well

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am going to give it to Anis just because Anis was faster. Close call.

Comment: @JonathanKomar Sure, his might be more accurate (subprocess.TimeoutExpired), editing my answer accordingly, and also to show how to print the default error if you do need it.